# Count if subtotal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a subtotal of numbers smaller than 3 in another sheet (named "Detail") were the formula is.  I have other subtotal formulas in the sheet that work fine, but I am unable to figure out this particular one.  The formula I have been trying to use is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000,ROW(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000)-ROW(Detail!$Q$7),0,1)),--(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000,"<3"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `SUMIF`?

Answer (score 1):

You have done a silly mistake, your formula needs simple correction in last part.

`--(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000,"<3"))` should written like this,

`--(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000<3))`.

Replace `,"<3"` with `<3` and rewritten formula should read like shown below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000,ROW(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000)-ROW(Detail!$Q$7),0,1)),--(Detail!$Q$7:$Q$4000<3))
```